# How to create a F# PCL with Xamarin.Studio?

Tags: f#, xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin-studio

I see the template for creating a C# PCL, but not a F# PCL. Somewhere, someone mentioned about installing the necessary templates.

Anybody knows better?

---

**About Xamarin Studio 5.9**

Does anybody knows if XS 5.9 will support F# PCLs?

Comment: Do you have F# installed in XS?

Comment: Yes. I can create normal F# library projects, but no F# Portable Class Library projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a F# PCL dll with Visual Studio and then add a reference to it from a project written in Xamarin Studio using PCL #78 (good enough for iOS, android, WP).